# Can I pass a query with https.get in node.js?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to pass a query in http.get.
This works:

```
https = require("https");
https.get('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/1109550759112324/accounts/test-users?access_token=token',
```

This results in a 404:

```
https = require("https");
https.get({
    host: 'graph.facebook.com',
    path: '/v2.6/1109550759112324/accounts/test-users',
    query: {
        access_token: 'token'
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no [`query` option](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) built into the `HTTP` or `HTTPS` library in Node Core when performing a request. Query strings are actually a separate module called [`querystring`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/querystring.html). Within that library there is the function [`stringify()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/querystring.html#querystring_querystring_stringify_obj_sep_eq_options) which will take an object and create a query string from that, essentially in the fashion that you're expecting the `https.get()` to do for you in your question.

You can use `querystring.stringify()` with `https.get()` like so

```
const https = require('https');
const qs = require('querystring');

let query = qs.stringify({ access_token: 'token' });

https.get({
    host: 'graph.facebook.com', 
    path: `/v2.6/1109550759112324/accounts/test-users?${query}`,    
}, (res) => {
    console.log(`StatusCode: ${res.statusCode}`);   
    let data = '';

    res.on('data', (chunk) => { data += chunk; });

    res.on('end', () => {
        // Parsing JSON response
        data = JSON.parse(data);

        console.log(`Body: ${JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}`); 
    });
}).on('error', (err) => {
    console.log(`Error: ${err}`);
});
```